# How can I select a column from a NOT-IN sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a query that I need help with:

```
SELECT s.lastfirst, s.student_number, s.grade_level
FROM students s
WHERE s.schoolid = 300 AND s.enroll_status = 0 AND s.id not in
(
    SELECT d.studentid
    FROM section_meeting em INNER JOIN sections e
    ON em.sectionid = e.id
    INNER JOIN cc d ON e.id = d.sectionid      
    WHERE em.schoolid = 300 and em.period_number in (P1)    
)
```

This query works fine except that I need to show the column em.period_number in the results as well. Can anyone suggest how to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your schema.  You can try joining together instead of using a `WHERE` clause.  This might allow you to `SELECT` the `period_number` field in your result.

Comment: Why is it `em.period_number in (P1)` rather than `em.period_number = P1`? On what table is the column named `P1`?

Comment: So you want to select all IDs that are not in a subselect while showing them a column from that subselect? That does not make any sense. Probably you should keep the subselect like it is now while joining other tables in the main select.

Comment: Correction:  em.period_number in (P1)    is     em.period_number in (1)    I made this mistake while I was trying out the sql and pasted unitentionally.  Sorry!

Comment: Mihai:  Yes, my intention is to pull the records that are NOT in the subquery because we need the data which is NOT in the subquery. I know it sounds werid but consider this. Of the 10 periods  on given day (period numbers 1 through 10), which are fixed values we know, we want to pull the student names who do not have a period in the table because that will be their "free" period. Basically, if the period has a class assigned then we have an entry in the database along with the period number and class name while for free periods no entry exists in the table :) Makes sense?

Comment: Guys, sorry, but I am not sure I can post the entire scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> query works fine exept that I need to show the column em.period_number
>   in the results as well

If you have successfully got the result using your question query let me add `period_number` with join query..try :

```
SELECT       s.lastfirst, s.student_number, s.grade_level, section_meeting.period_number
FROM         students  s INNER JOIN
             section_meeting ON s.schoolid = section_meeting.schoolid
WHERE        (s.schoolid = 300) AND (s.enroll_status = 0) AND (s.id NOT IN
             (SELECT        d.studentid
             FROM         section_meeting  em INNER JOIN
                          sections  e ON em.sectionid = e.id INNER JOIN
                          cc  d ON e.id = d.sectionid
                          WHERE        (em.schoolid = 300) AND (em.period_number IN (P1))))
```

Comment: 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended" I am running the query in the sql developer. It's an oracle database.

Comment: i have quoted that if you get the output for your posted query then sure the solution posted will give you result..(there was missing definition for P in your code)

Comment: @horizon22 let me edit..please check the updated one

Comment: If I put 1 instead of P1 the original query works. That was a mistake on my part, sorry. Oh wow! The query executed.Give me some time to verify the data. Thanks for pulling me up to this point!

Comment: Why tag with sql server if it is an Oracle DB?

Comment: You can call it a mistake but I thought MS SQL was more appropriate because, we're doing it in an incredible way. A vendor who designed some reports for us designed the system used SQL server reporting services from where he connected the system to the software which contains our main db, which is an oracle databse. :)

Comment: @horizon22 was post useful ?

Comment: I am able to pull the column in the results that I needed from a sub-query. Thankful to all of you for your swift replies.